# How to extract JSON keys from a return URL in WooCommerce for authentication

Tags: php, swift, woocommerce, alamofire

I'm working on an iOS application written in Swift that authorizes store administrators through the WooCommerce Application Authentication Endpoint

This endpoint has five parameters app_name, scope, user_id, return_url, and callback_url. I'm using this URL format: `http://example.com&/wc-auth/v1/authorize/?app_name=MyAppName&scope=read_write&user_id=123&return_url=http://app.com&callback_url=https://app.com`. I send the user to their website for authorization

The above redirects the user using return_url, this return URL is "in my app's case" an iOS [Universal Link](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) that sends the user back to the app, with success and user_id parameters as query strings. Success sends 0 if the user denied, or 1 if authenticated successfully. The user is being authenticated and the keys are being created in WooCommerce.

According to the [Woo REST API documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#rest-api-keys):
The auth endpoint will send the API Keys in JSON format to the callback_url, so it's important to remember that some languages such as PHP will not display it inside the $_POST global variable, in PHP you can access it using $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA (for old PHP versions) or file_get_contents('php://input');.
The URL generated must have all query string values encoded.

This is an example JSON returned:

```
{
    "key_id": 1,
    "user_id": 123,
    "consumer_key": "ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "consumer_secret": "cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "key_permissions": "read_write"
}
```

Which URL gets read first?
How exactly does the callback_url communicate with the return URL? Should I get the JSON from the return URL or the callback URL? Are these values extracted from the URL itself or from a post request for which I could use AlamoFire?

Answer (score 1):

When using universal links, the app will be opened with the parameters in a URL. **No POST data is accessible that way**.
In my opinion, you can create a helper web page (or use an existing one) which reads and parses the data in the input and create the suitable universal link with the information you need (`consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`, etc.) as query string.

For example:

```
yourapp://auth_result?consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxx
```

You can access these query string items in your application easily.

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured out how to extract the URL in scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity Now the problem is that the return URL from WooCommerce does not have any data to extract and add to the URL. I'm using a Universal link not a URL Scheme but it is the same concept.

Comment: Have you used a helper web page to read the posted data and parse it? (before redirecting to the application), because the url you get directly in the application, does not contain any POST data from original url.

Comment: I went a different route. I'm having the user scan a QR Code generated by WooCommerce therefore adding the keys to the app. It avoids having to open Safari to login. Someone can see the url if they know how to do it.